# OpenBinaryDirect() Runtime exeption : This property cannot be set after writing has started

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

i am trying to download docs from sharepoint document library using C#.

Now Getting an exception "This property cannot be set after writing has started " on openBinaryDirect() method.

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.dll

Additional information: This property cannot be set after writing has started."

Please help me to resolve this issue. is there any other method to download docs from sharepoint (csom) .

```
ClientContext ctx;
ctx = new ClientContext("url");


string pass = "pass";
SecureString secureString = new SecureString();

foreach (char c in pass.ToCharArray())
{
    secureString.AppendChar(c);
}
ctx.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(".onmicrosoft.com",secureString);

FileCollection files = ctx.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl("Salary document Demo").Files;

ctx.Load(files);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File file in files)
{

    FileInformation fileInfo = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(ctx, file.ServerRelativeUrl);

    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    var filePath = @"c:\downloads" + file.Name;
    using (var fileStream = new System.IO.FileStream(filePath, System.IO.FileMode.Create))
    {
        fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(fileStream);
    }
}
```

Comment: its because you are reusing the fileInfo object inside the loop.

Comment: so what i can do else. any suggestions ?

Comment: can you debug and find out where exactly this is coming? also what is the value in the filepath variable?

Comment: getting the error in Fileinfromation fileinfo= .....  LINE , to be exact on ctx variable. and the execution stop over there after exception. file path is the local drive location to save the data after downloading.

Comment: Please check this blog - https://tahoeninjas.blog/2018/03/28/saving-files-from-a-sharepoint-document-library-to-a-local-folder-using-csom/

Answer (score 2):

Resolved this issue by installing a new Nuget Package :

Microsoft.Sharepoint.2013.Client.16

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Sharepoint.2013.Client.16/